# TinyMCE 6 and xml elements

Tags: xml, tinymce

TinyMCE 6 removes/strips the body tag.

For example, when I paste the following into the source code window

```
<body xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml">
<p>test</p>
</body>
```

it is filtered into

```
<p>test</p>
```

How can I keep the body tag?

I've the following settings:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  encoding: 'raw',
  element_format : 'xhtml',
```

Note that TinyMCE 5 preserves body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I used is to add back the `body` tag when saving with `save_onsavecallback`, like so:

```
var blob = new Blob(['<body>' + i.value+ '</body>'], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Full Page plugin (which would allow the body tag) was removed in TinyMCE 6.0

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes59/#thefullpagefullpageplugin

Currently (as of Oct 2022) the only way to retain the body tag would be to use TinyMCE 5